# WebAPI Post [FormBody] accepts any value as bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have below function written in WebAPI

```
 public async Task<bool> Post([FromBody] bool val)
  {

  }
```

this function is accepting any value as bool ex:
When I pass true, it treats as true
When I pass false, it treats as false
**When I pass abc, it treats as false**

I want to have some sort of validation where it either gives

> 400 or ModelState.IsValid as false.

Comment: make val nullable and then if null perform your logic

Comment: If you instead of `[FromBody]` use `[FromUri]` it will return a 400 status code when `val` is not a boolean value